# Define TypeScript callback type and provide default callback value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am having trouble providing a default callback value AND tracking the return type of that callback

In the following case, `a` and `b` both have type `any` but I'd like them to have the return type of whatever `callback` returns. In this case `string` and `number` but in principle, it could be anything

```
const defaultCallback = () => 'Hello World'

function main(callback: () => any = defaultCallback){
  return callback()
}

const a = main(() => 'Foo') <-- Type is any but should be string
const b = main(() => 1000) <-- Type is any but should be number
const c = main() <-- Type is any but should be string
```

So to solve for that I've tried a number of things including introducing generics in the following way. This definition works correctly except that I don't seem to be able to provide a default value anymore.

```
const defaultCallback = () => 'Hello World'

function main<T extends any>(callback: () => T = defaultCallback): T {
  return callback()
}

const a = main(() => 'Hello World') <--- Type string 
const b = main(() => 1000) <--- Type number
const c = main() <-- Should be acceptable which requires a default value for callback
```

The above code works without `defaultCallback` but with `defaultCallback` I receive:

`Type '() => string' is not assignable to type '() => T'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'unknown'.(2322)`

Comment: `const defaultCallback: any`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with little help of overloadings:

```js
const defaultCallback = () => 'Hello World'

function main<R>(callback: () => R): R
function main(): ReturnType<typeof defaultCallback>
function main(callback = defaultCallback) {
    return callback()
}

const a = main(() => 'Foo')    // string
const b = main(() => 1000)     // number
const c = main()               // string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwGYEMCuAbKBhFGMBGKwA1jALwwAUAlBQHwwDkAEgviDAOogBOGcJgCghSNGGBQAluBgBbFFLAAeAEr0qwPIWIkAXNTrlGqmgdWjxkmWHmKwtcwihpeYACoBPAA4JlUHwQQJHhkdCxcfCJSeksJaVkFJU1taLJKRFRMHFTdOgBvIRhimF5nV1stKN1aIQBfEVBIWBQKO2TaBmYAMRAQJjoSgHohmGheJQBzISboGAI2pIdO4xgARgAGLcHh0bA0OQIEXhnwOeBF%2006Sm9vikbGoCbBJoA)